# Comparing a sys.arvg to a list

Tags: python, linux

So what I am trying to do is compare a terminal argument against a list in my code.

so for example, I will put a command in like "python ./mycode.py -name.

So I want to compare the argument -name to a list I have in my code.

At the moment it looks something like this:

```
reqArgs = ["-name", "-age", "-date"]

for arg in sys.argv:
  for req in arg:
    if req in reqArgs:
      print "Sucess"
    else:
      print "not working"
```

I know I am not that far off. What am I missing here?

Comment: `for req in arg:`? Huh? That's going to be iterating over character-by-character -- first `-`, then `n`, then `a`, etc.

Comment: And your first assignment won't even be accepted by the interpreter at all unless you have variables named `name`, `age` and `date` of a type amenable to negation.

Comment: `reqArgs` are meant to be strings inside that list, right? Could you edit this to include the actual code, with quotes around strings, if present?

Comment: Anyhow, the best-practice way to parse arguments is with the [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html). Learning it sooner rather than later will do you good.

Comment: @Charles Duffy I had come across argparse but I was not sure if that was what I was looking for. I will look a little closer at it. Thank you.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Thanks for catching that. yes those are meant to be strings. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

You are missing `argparse`. Do your argument parsing with argparse, and you get automatic help messages, reasonable error messages when required arguments are missing, a consistent user interface.

Consider this  program with your three required arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import dateutil.parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='The Constant Frobulator')
parser.add_argument('-name', required=True,
                    help='The name of frobulator')
parser.add_argument('-age', required=True,
                    type=int,
                    help='The age of frobulator')
parser.add_argument('-date', required=True,
                    type=dateutil.parser.parse,
                    help='The precise date frobulation began')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

And this demonstration of the program's features, courtesy argparse:

```
$ ./myprog
usage: myprog [-h] -name NAME -age AGE -date DATE
myprog: error: argument -name is required
$ ./myprog -h
usage: myprog [-h] -name NAME -age AGE -date DATE

The Constant Frobulator

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -name NAME  The name of frobulator
  -age AGE    The age of frobulator
  -date DATE  The precise date frobulation began
$ ./myprog -name George -age 47 -date "Mar 5, 2016"
Namespace(age=47, date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 5, 0, 0), name='George')
$ ./myprog -name George -age 47.5 -date "Mar 5, 2016"
usage: myprog [-h] -name NAME -age AGE -date DATE
myprog: error: argument -age: invalid int value: '47.5'
$ ./myprog -name George -date "Mar 5, 2016"
usage: myprog [-h] -name NAME -age AGE -date DATE
myprog: error: argument -age is required
```

Comment: Thank you, this was great. I was reading up on argparse and was not very clear on it, but this clears things up very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a single loop and reqArgs should be strings

```
reqArgs = ['-name', '-age', '-date']

for arg in reqArgs:
    if arg in sys.argv:
      print "Success"
    else:
      print "not working"
```

A better solution:

```
req_args = ['-name', '-age', '-date']
found_all_req_args = all(arg in sys.argv for arg in req_args)
```

Even better:

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

Comment: That took care of it. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Then please accept the answer

Comment: I will as soon as it lets me. Says i have to wait 4 more min lol